# Is Openbox a non-reparenting window manager?

Tags: openbox

Installing jre7-openjdk prints this message:

> when you use a non-reparenting window manager set
>   _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 in /etc/profile.d/jre.sh

My WM is openbox, have I to edit the file?

Comment: `/etc/profile.d` is a weird place. The choice of window manager is a per-user setting. That means it should be set within the users home directory e.g. `$HOME/.profile`.

Answer (score 3):

The [re-parenting window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-parenting_window_manager) article on Wikipedia strongly implies that openbox is a reparenting wm:

> Virtually all modern window managers are re-parenting, although
> earlier window managers, such as the uwm window manager, were not.
> Exceptions to that rule are dwm, cwm, PLWM, ratpoison and xmonad,
> due to a lack of any typical window decorations used by these window
> managers, and also Compiz which drew the decorations separately up
> until version 0.9.0, where it became a re-parenting window manager to
> allow it to run in a non-composited mode.

Comment: For awesomewm users, this page http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java states that awesome is a non-reparenting window manager.

Comment: awesome is a reparenting window manager [since 2010](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/commit/102063dbbdfb0bc9f43268d98f7dcb5269547395). [See also](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/commit/86ca5281f489c5183069722961c88f275e534a8a): "This is the current version of the FAQ in the wiki converted to markdown, but some IMO bogus content was stripped (e.g. references to awesome being a non-reparenting WM)."

Answer (score 2):

This is already answered (and goldilocks is right), but the answer isn't direct. To remedy this: No. Openbox is a reparenting WM. Just about any WM with "fancy" window borders is re-parenting. I know of no window manager with borders that is non-reparenting.

Comment: To make this even clearer: Xorg provides a simple form of "borders" that is not indicative of non-reparenting wms. If there's a simple {n}px border on all sides of a window (think dwm) it may not be reparenting. However, the sorts of borders that openbox (and most modern wms) draw require reparenting.